# Removing header and footer section from scraped data

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to remove the header and footer section if available in a scraped data.

**Code**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
service = Service("/home/ubuntu/selenium_drivers/chromedriver")

URL = "https://www.uh.edu/kgmca/music/events/calendar/?view=e&id=30723#event"
try:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = service, options = options)
    driver.get(URL)
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    html_content = driver.page_source
    driver.quit()
except WebDriverException:
    driver.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content)
text = soup.getText(separator=u' ')
```

I tried removing tags but its not working. How it can be achieved.

Comment: can you show us the code that tries to remove the header and footer?

Comment: Give me few moments. Let me revert my code back and will produce here

Comment: oh. i tried wrong method..

Comment: what are the two links that it isn't working with?

Comment: https://annapolissymphony.org/events/orion-youth-orchestra-inaugural-concert/ For this link its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**

Just get the element and  use `.extract()`.

**Option 2:**

The `<main>` tag is right in between the `<header>` and `<footer>` tags. Provided you *only* want that part, you could just say:

`main = soup.find('main')`

Also, any reason you're using Selenium? Doesn't simply using `requests` do the trick?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
service = Service("/home/ubuntu/selenium_drivers/chromedriver")

URL = "https://www.uh.edu/kgmca/music/events/calendar/?view=e&id=30723#event"
try:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = service, options = options)
    driver.get(URL)
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    html_content = driver.page_source
    driver.quit()
except WebDriverException:
    driver.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content)
text = soup.getText(separator=u' ')


for each in ['header','footer']:
    s = soup.find(each)
    s.extract()
```

Comment: Some pages are not working very well with other module. So I chose selenium. Is there any drawback in using selenium

Comment: It's just slower. That's all.

Comment: i tried with two different links : a2so.com/event-directory/movie-magic and annapolissymphony.org/events/….. For the first link its working and second one its not. What can be the reason. 

`soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content)
for each in ['header','footer']:
    s = soup.find(each)
    if s == None:
        continue
    else:
        s.extract()

text = soup.getText(separator=u' ')`

This is how i used

Comment: Have you got any idea why its not working. Tried with decompose too. Still not working

Comment: I have around 500 different urls to scrape. Most of them have header and footer tags. Some dont have. In my line of work, i dont need data within header and footer tags if present. From the extraction code, data within headers and footers tags from few are not removed  eventhough tags are present

Comment: I’ll take a look at that tomorrow morning.

Comment: You need to look at the html source. For the two links you mentioned, the tags are present, but instead of calling it `<header>` tag, they use the tag `<head>`. So try changing that list in the loop to `['head','header','footer']`