# Collecting the data displayed in browser but not in response

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

**The Situation**

I am trying to scrape webpages to get some data.
I need the html data which is viewable in the browser as a whole for my application.

**The Problem**

But when I scrape some urls, I am getting data which are not viewable from browser. But in the html code its there. So is there any way to scrape the data which is viewable only in the browser

**Code**

```py
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
    
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    service = Service("/home/nebu/selenium_drivers/chromedriver")
    
    URL = "https://augustasymphony.com/event/top-of-the-world/"
    try:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = service, options = options)
        driver.get(URL)
        driver.implicitly_wait(2)
        html_content = driver.page_source
        driver.quit()
    except WebDriverException:
        driver.quit()
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content)
    for each in ['header','footer']:
            s = soup.find(each)
            if s == None:
                continue
            else:
                s.extract()
    text = soup.getText(separator=u' ')
    print(text)
```

**The Question**

Where am I going wrong here?
How can I go about debugging this?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what is happening during the scraping.. because if it is within the HTML returned then technically you can collect said data?

Comment: @Kwsswart In the html code i am getting that data. But i want only the data which is viewable in browser window.

Comment: The HTML is what is veiwable in the browser. could you post a copy of the html that you receive that I can try see the issue within that please

Comment: Usually when you scrape a page you get the entire page at once and then you need to work through that page to only take the data that you want from the entire html

Comment: first: server may detect `Selenium` and send different content. Second: some elements may be in HTML but they may not be displayed because it may use `CSS` to hide it - but `BeautifulSoup` can't use `CSS` to remove it. Better use `BeautifulSoup` or `Selenium` to get only values which you really need - but it need more complex code.

Comment: @Kwsswart Cant copy the entire html code. Its too lengthy. Im sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply a case of you needing to extract the data in a more specific manner.

***You have 2 options really:***

**Option 1:** (In my opinion the better, as it is faster  and less resource heavy.)

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


headers = {'Accept': '*/*',
 'Connection': 'keep-alive',
 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683 Safari/537.36 OPR/57.0.3098.91'}
res = requests.get("https://augustasymphony.com/event/top-of-the-world/", headers=headers)
soup = bs(res.text, "lxml")

event_header = soup.find("h2", {"class": "rhino-event-header"}).text.strip()
time = soup.find("p", {"class": "rhino-event-time"}).text.strip()
```

You can use requests quite simply to find the data as shown in the code above specifically selecting the data you want and perhap saving it in a dictionary. This is the normal way to go about it. It may contain a lot of scripts in the page, however the page doesn't require JavaScript to load said data dynamically.

Option2:

You continue using selenium and can collect the entire body information of the page using one of multiple selections.

```py
driver.find_element_by_id('wrapper').get_attribute('innerHTML') # Entire body
driver.find_element_by_id('tribe-events').get_attribute('innerHTML') # the events list
driver.find_element_by_id('rhino-event-single-content').get_attribute('innerHTML') # the single event
```

This second option is a lot more just taking the whole html and dumping it.

Personally I would go with the first option creating dictionaries of the cleaned data.

**Edit:**

To futher illustrate my example

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
headers = {'Accept': '*/*',
 'Connection': 'keep-alive',
 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683 Safari/537.36 OPR/57.0.3098.91'}
res = requests.get("https://augustasymphony.com/event/", headers=headers)
soup = bs(res.text, "lxml")
seedlist = {a["href"] for a in soup.find("div", {"id": "tribe-events-content-wrapper"}).find_all("a") if '?ical=1' not in a["href"]}
for seed in seedlist:
    res = requests.get(seed, headers=headers)
    soup = bs(res.text, "lxml")
    data = dict()
    data['event_header'] = soup.find("h2", {"class": "rhino-event-header"}).text.strip()
    data['time'] = soup.find("p", {"class": "rhino-event-time"}).text.strip()
    print(data)
```

Here I am generting a seedlist of event urls and then going into each one to find information.

Comment: If there is only one url, first option will be good. But if there are around 400 different base urls, with different format and structure, which option will be better.

Comment: usually if it is from the same website the structure will be the same

Comment: I have editted the answer to further illustrate the point above. If trying to generically get data from many different websites with different structures and information then you will note that it will require designing different processes for each one as the location of the data depends on different sites, however usually the sae domain follows the same structure as they are automatically generated

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your valuable advice. Let me check the whole thing

Comment: Can i ask a question related to scraping. Another issue which im facing is posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69707833/removing-header-and-footer-section-from-scraped-data

Comment: sure what are the two links that it isn't working wiht

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238547/discussion-between-kwsswart-and-imhans33).

Comment: Ok i am there...

Answer (score 0):

It's because some websites detect if it's a web browser.

So they don't send the HTML file back.

That's why there is no HTML send back